# Disable right click in Win form app

Tags: c#, .net

Hii I am making a windows Form application 
I added a user control in that application 
Is there a way to disable the right click event.
because if I use

```
Button.click += SomeMethod
```

It is going to someMethod in case of both (left and right) clicks.
I want to do this action in case of left click only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you handle which button has been clicked inside of the event?

```
private void uc_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         //more logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect which button of mouse was clicked inside event handler.

Check [MouseEventArgs e](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) argument of handler

Answer (score 1):

You can check the button and call the native onClick for cases of left-button click.

[pseudo code]

```
SomeMethod(e){
  if (e.Button == left){
    control.onClick(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do number of ways;

1) if you want to use your button.click event then do the code below:

```
Button.Click += SomeMethod;
private void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Button bt = sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button;

     if (bt != null)
     {
        if (bt.Equals(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left))
        {
                // do something;
         }
     }
}
```

2) Or use the mouse clicked event in windows form "button.MouseClick".

```
   Button.MouseClick += SomeMethod;
   private void SomeMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
        if (!e.Button.Equals(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right))
        {
            // do work
        }
   }
```

I was hoping that we could use the e.Handled = true, but in this case neither of the event argument has the Handled property, therefore you have to manually check them.