# How to disable right click in windows desktop using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using c# form, I have two button just like on, off. When I click on/off button I need to enable/disable mouse right button on windows desktop. How can I do that?

I try the registry, but not work well as I expect.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Usually your application should not affect how the OS or other applications work. Messing around with global system settings may result in angry users or even broken systems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911660/disable-right-click-in-win-form-app

Comment: @JonasH I'm building Atm software. So I need few things. Like a this subject.

Comment: If you are building ATM software your user should most likely not have access to the desktop at all, See [windows kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app)